# How to add UIView as header view for UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` where I am trying to add a UIView as the header view to the collectionview. My current attempt is not displaying the UIView after a good amount of time of following a multitude of guides. I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

My current approach:

`Set height of supplemental view and register`

```
ViewDidLoad(){
   CollectionView.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView(typeof(CollectionHeader), UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, "HeaderView");
   UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
   layout.HeaderReferenceSize = setHeader(this).Frame.Size; //setHeader returns a UIView
   CollectionView.SetCollectionViewLayout(layout, true);
}
```

`Gets the supplemental view`

```
public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement(UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    CollectionHeader headerView = (CollectionHeader)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, "HeaderView", indexPath);
    headerView.owner = this;
    headerView.view = setHeader(this);//setHeader returns a UIView
    return headerView;
}
```

`Create my view via a class (not really sure how/why to do this)`

```
public class CollectionHeader : UICollectionReusableView {
    public UIView view { 
        get { return view; }
        set { view = value; SetNeedsDisplay();}
    }
    public PhotographController owner;
    [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public CollectionHeader(System.Drawing.RectangleF frame) :base(frame) {
        view = new UIView(setHeader(owner).Frame);
        AddSubview(view);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can not get your point very clearly, do you just want to hide the supplementary view when reach some conditions?

Comment: Hello, You are getting any solution for this issue ?